# Possible short circuit after plugging a wrong cable?

Tags: power-supply, cable

So basically,I switched the power cable that goes in the monitor with the power cable that goes to my PC box since they look the same. My PC worked like that for 1 hour, untill I realized I messed up. I switched the cables and my PC still works fine. I'm afraid that my PC will die because I'm kinda short on money and can't afford a new motherboard/power supply or basically anything.

Comment: Power cables are power cables. The only time it might matter is if there is an adapter involved. Sometimes the PC power cable will be larger gauge and better shielded than a monitor cable, but there still would be no risk of shorting anything out by swapping them.

Comment: Adapters you say? A wrong adapter is the reason why my pirated NES console burned to ashes.

Comment: Yes, adapters put out very specific voltage/amperage, so mixing those can cause damage to a device if it receives way more than is intended for the device (eg, the device doesn't have an internal component like a PC power supply to regulate, it relies on the adapter to do that).

Comment: And what was I doing when this was mentioned back in my old school?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No harm was done.

Most cables between a wall socket and a computer are interchangeable. And if you do cause a short circuit you are likely to find out immediately and not hours later.

Things being compatible is why at least [one end of most power cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320_C14#C14) is standarized.

[image: Standard power cable]

Now there are plenty exceptions to this. But most of those also have different plugs on one or both sides of the cable and you will not find some of those in a typical consumer setup (e.g. 400v 3-phase connections rather than the regular 240v).

Comment: You definitely would notice a short pretty quickly. A short is when a path change is made that causes electricity to follow a different path (newly created path has lower resistance) and the change causes an overload as the new path is not designed for the current it takes, so the effects would be immediate and noticeable. Sometimes shorts don't cause damage as there is short circuit protection built into the circuitry, but you would still notice something wasn't right (eg, the unit would probably shut down).

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, they should be identical. If you are talking about these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320_C14#C14

Comment: I hope you are right. If you are wrong then time will tell I guess. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes,I would choose this as an accepted answer but..it's kinda hard to get a clear answer when you have to read about something you do not understand and that is not written in your mother language (+a lot of text). BUT your answer is much appreciated too. I would rate it as useful too,but I don't have enough rep. Thanks to you too sir.

Comment: @Hennes Your answer + my link would be the best though, my answer was a bit short.